# Writing a unit test case in node.js using mocha to mock a azure service bus queue to recive messages

Tags: node.js, azure, unit-testing, sinon

I have written a unit test case,but it is giving error.
   Please find the code below

```
index.js

const { ServiceBusClient, ReceiveMode } = require("@azure/service-bus");

module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {

// Define connection string and related Service Bus entity names here
const connectionString = process.env['serviceBusConnectionString'];
const queueName = process.env['serviceBusQueueName'];
const sbClient = ServiceBusClient.createFromConnectionString(connectionString);
const queueClient = sbClient.createQueueClient(queueName);
//const receiver = queueClient.createReceiver(ReceiveMode.receiveAndDelete);
const receiver = queueClient.createReceiver(ReceiveMode.peekLock);

const messages = await receiver.receiveMessages(1);
try {

    let payloads = [];
    messages.forEach((msg) => {
        payloads.push(msg.body);
    })

    await queueClient.close();
} catch (err) {
    context.log('Queue message status settle: abandon');
    await messages[0].abandon();
    console.log('Error ', err);
} finally {
    await sbClient.close();
    context.done();
}
```

};

This is the unit test file and I am getting error.Please let me know why I am getting this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50EFY.png)

indexTest.js:

```
beforeEach(() => {
        const sbClientStub = {
            createQueueClient: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
            createReceiver: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
            receiveMessages:sinon.stub(),
            close: sinon.stub(),
        };
        sinon.stub(ServiceBusClient, 'createFromConnectionString').callsFake(() => sbClientStub);
        const ctx = {};
        // const actual = await pushToQueue(message, ctx);
        // sinon.assert.match(actual, 2);
        sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(ServiceBusClient.createFromConnectionString, undefined);
        sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(sbClientStub.createQueueClient, undefined);
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(sbClientStub.createReceiver, undefined );
        //sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(sbClientStub.send.firstCall, { body: 'a' });
        //sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(sbClientStub.send.secondCall, { body: 'b' });
        sinon.assert.calledTwice(sbClientStub.close); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace every `sinon.stub()` with `sinon.spy()`. The stub will prevent calling the original implementation of methods, but spies will do. They basically have the same APIs.

In order to call the original methods of `@azure/service-bus`, make sure the resources of `@azure/service-bus` are ready such as environment variables, service account, queue and so on.

If you do this, the unit tests are no longer isolated. In fact, they are no longer unit tests, but integration tests, or e2e tests.